# What happends when two li-po batteries with a small difference in voltages are connected in parallel

Tags: batteries

Basically i'm trying to build a huge power bank with 3.7v 10000mAh 1s cells. I'm increasing the capacity to 50000 mah by stacking one cell over the other in parallel. All the cells are identical in chemistry and nominal voltage. Does it actually affects the batteries when I connect a fully charged cell (4.2v) and a half charged cell (3.9v) in parallel ???

Comment: The advice you were given on your other question was clear - use a proper charging system see : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/374541/152903

Answer (score 5):

Before connecting cells in parallel you **MUST** balance them. Read more about that on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_balancing).

Balancing means, bringing the cells to **the same voltage**. After balancing **measure** the voltage and make sure the voltage difference is less than 0.05 V or thereabout (that value of 50 mV is my personal guess).

If you skip this step, the 4.2 V cell will **charge** the 3.9 V cell. This isn't so bad **but** the current at which this charging/discharging is **uncontrolled** and that **is** a problem. The current can become too large and that will **damage** the cells.

Balancing can be done by connecting the cells in parallel but not directly, there must be a resistor connected between them. The resistor then limits the current to a safe level.

Comment: what if the discharge rate of each cell is 0.5C which is 0.5x10A= 5 Amperes.

Comment: *What if* what ? Your comment-question does not relate in any way to my answer. You really should try to understand (how to treat) batteries better before doing anything.

Comment: All the batteries will have their over current protection circuit included in the pack. Will that not be enough to control the over current coming into it??

Comment: No, the protection is not intended for that purpose. The protection will **disconnect** the battery when the current exceeds a limit. Think of that protection as a fuse that will restore itself when the fault condition is removed. the protection will not and cannot regulate the current. To do that it would need to dissipate a lot of power and it cannot do that, it is not designed for that.

Comment: @dim I did, well spotted :-)

Comment: @ Bimpelrekkie, Thank you for your information. One more thing, when two battery packs with different SOC (state of charge) are connected in parallel can I use schottky diodes from the battery terminals so that the diodes stops entering of the high current from higher voltage battery into lower voltage battery . If not pls suggest me some better ways to achieve. All I need to do is I have to connect two isolated 9000 mAh batteries in parallel having their own BMS.

Comment: Yes you can use (Schottky) diodes to stop one cell charging the other. Then the cell with the highest voltage will be discharged until the voltages of the cells are equal, then both will discharge. **But** you can only use the diodes for discharging, with the diodes in place you will be unable to **charge** the cells as if they're one large battery. But as a temporary solution, diodes can be used.

Comment: I will use two parallel paths... one for charging with out diodes and other for protection with diodes

Comment: I do not see how that would work. The diodes can only be a **temporary** solution when discharging. When the cells are empty they will have the same voltage so they will then be balanced and you can connect them in parallel (without diodes) and treat the whole as **one** battery. I do not see what benefit it would bring to do things differently. You're just over complicating things very likely due to lack of understanding.

Answer (score 2):

These are not small differences in this context. What might happen is the fully charged cell would charge the other cell at a high rate, exactly the same as if you used a 100A 4.2V supply to charge the cell with no current limiting. If a small fault also occurred, you would have a fire.

If the cells are closer, say 80% and 90% charged, or 4.1/4.0 volts, the balance current would be less (but still uncontrolled).